# Are there any differences among suffixes 'er', 'or', 'ee', 'eer', and 'ist'?

Tags: word-choice, suffixes

I guess they are all 'agent markers'. As people obviously don't say 'actists' for actors so I guess they are not interchangeable. But where are the differences?

e.g.

-er:
painter

-or:
creator

-ee:
trainee

-eer:
volunteer

-ist:
cyclist

Comment: You can look up the definitions for each suffix to get an idea of potential differences, but mostly it comes down to the fact that for any *given* noun, one or other is the "idiomatically established" choice. But ***-er*** is the standard "productive" default for new usages, ***-or*** is more likely with "active agents", ***-ee*** for "patient noun" (thing/person *acted upon*), and ***-ist*** is more associated with ideologies (aka ***-isms***).

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few guidelines for these suffixes:

- `er` and `or` are both suffixes used to turn a verb into a noun by referring to the person/agent responsible for the action.  The one rule I could find for the distinction between `-er` and `-or` is that [Latin-based words tend to use `-or`](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/4734).  Otherwise, it's more common to use `-er` instead.  This can refer to any agent (person, thing, event etc) that does the action.  For example, a mixer is something that blends (mixes) other things together.  It can be an electric kitchen device to aid mixing ingredients; it can be the person whose duty it is to mix stuff; it can even be an event whose purpose is to get a bunch of strangers to "blend together" and interact.
- `-ee` suffix is used to mean a person who is the target/recipient of an action.  So for example, the trainee is a person receiving training.  Compare this to the trainer, who is the person in charge of trainer the new trainee.
- `-ist` refers to specifically a person who does something or is associated with something.  Non-person agents are not typical of this suffix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you made their distinctions easy to understand, appreciated it! I just added '-eer' to the question (I can't believe I forgot to mention it! ), would you mind... ?

Comment: Just did a quick [google search for `suffix eer`](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASVA_enUS638US638&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=suffix%20eer).  It's not terribly related to the other suffixes.

Comment: In particular, "-or" tends to be used as an ending for words that can take "-ion" as an ending.